# Import js file into Vue.js project

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Please pardon my lack of knowledge on js bundling but I would like to import this javascript file into my Vue.js project and use its function and I just can't see to get it to work.

https://github.com/omnisci/Charting-Sample/blob/master/main.js

Maybe this is just something fundamental about how the file was bundled but I am trying to import it like this

```
import * as omni from "../main";
```

and then trying to use a function from the file like this

```
omni.crossfilter.crossfilter(con, tableName)
```

But I am getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: _omni__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.crossfilter is not a function
```

When I just include the file in regular html file using a src and script tag it works just fine calling the function. If anyone could give me some guidance on what I am doing wrong here, or how to import this properly I would really appreciate it.

Comment: have you tried `import omni from "../omni"`? Might sometimes also be `import { omni } from "../omni"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48426972/importing-javascript-file-for-use-within-vue-component This may help you.

Comment: It also depends on how you exported your function from main.js. Can you also add your omni snippet?

Comment: This is the file that the functions are exported in. I didn't write it so I was not sure if it would even work with vue. https://github.com/omnisci/Charting-Sample/blob/master/main.js

Answer (score 0):

Just write:

```
import '../main'
```

and call functions after import:

```
/ ...
crossfilter(con, tableName)
```

Comment: This is still telling me "error  'crossfilter' is not defined". I edited my question so that it is more clear what I am importing. (I had renamed the file main.js to omni.js)

Comment: The minified file just generate global variables. Try to console.log(crossFilter) after import to check it.