# ES6 import inside a vue component via business logic

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vue-component

So I am quite simply looking at how I can do a regular import e.g.

```
import { something } from 'myfantastic/package';
```

or even in a case:

```
import 'myfantastic/package/js/something.js';
```

I know I can do this within my `<script>` tag as a normal import but what I am trying to do is load a free package or pro package based on an `env` variable.

So I would like to be able do something like the following:

```
export default {
    created() {
        const something = ({something}) => import('myfantastic/package');
        something.add( data )
    }   
}
```

If possible I would like to be able to do this for standard scripts e.g. `'myfantastic/package/js/something.js';` and CSS files e.g. `'myfantastic/package/css/style.css'`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing javascript file for use within vue component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48426972/importing-javascript-file-for-use-within-vue-component)

Comment: No it doesn't, I'm trying to load it programmatically within my vue component rather than make it accessible to it.

Comment: checkout [lazyload](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html) it may help you

Comment: You can use [dynamic imports](https://v8.dev/features/dynamic-import), at this point they're pretty [well supported](https://caniuse.com/es6-module-dynamic-import)