# How do I import tiff.js to my Vue project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to view the .tif file in my Vue, so I try to use the tiff.js.

I try it in a "test.html" and use this to import the tiff.min.js.

```
<script src="./tiff.min.js">
</script>
```

However, there is no export from tiff.min.js so I don't know how to import that to my vue-cli.

```
<script>
export default ({
    name:"test",
    methods:{
        show(file){
            var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
    return function (e) {
      var buffer = e.target.result;
      var tiff = new Tiff({buffer: buffer});
      var canvas = tiff.toCanvas();
      var width = tiff.width();
      var height = tiff.height();
      if (canvas) {
        $('#output').empty().append(canvas);
      }
    };
    })(file);
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        }

    
    }
})
</script>
```

there is something wrong:"Could not find name 'Tiff'. Did you mean 'tiff'?Vetur(2570)"

Comment: I know how to import a XXX.js that has "export default"to a vue component, but the tiff.js doesn't have, so how to do that

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is addressed in this StackOverflow question if you want to import the js file in your Vue component
[Importing javascript file for use within vue component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48426972/importing-javascript-file-for-use-within-vue-component)

or your other options could be
https://github.com/photopea/UTIF.js or https://github.com/image-js/tiff

Comment: But the tiff.is has no export so I can't import it in the script

Comment: the runtime add method will add it like a simple JavaScript source so you can directly use its functionality like a vanilla JavaScript code